# DateTime.ParseExact format for custom date

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, datetime, timezone-offset

Im unable to use the function parseexact to transform the following String to Date

This one works:

```
Dim fechaS = "Feb 16 23:13:53.241 2015"
fecha1 = DateTime.ParseExact(fechaS, "MMM dd HH:mm:ss.fff yyyy", Nothing)
```

But fails, when I add a couple more options:

```
Dim fechaS = "Mon 16 23:13:53.241 UTC 2015"
fecha1 = DateTime.ParseExact(fechaS, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss.fff z yyyy", Nothing)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example has three issues with it:

1. The datetime string is not the same format as the date
2. The date string has no month in it so this can't be parsed into a date without knowing this.
3. There is no valid datetime specifier to match "UTC". In order to adjust for timezones you have to supply a timezone offset (this is what the `z` signifies) . You could to this by replacing `UTC` with `+0`

This fails

```
Dim fechaS = "Mon 16 23:13:53.241 UTC 2015"
fecha1 = DateTime.ParseExact(fechaS, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss.fff z yyyy", Nothing)
```

This works

```
Dim fechaS = "Mon Feb 16 23:13:53.241 UTC 2015"
fecha1 = DateTime.ParseExact(fechaS.Replace("UTC", "+0"), "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss.fff z yyyy", Nothing)
```

More info here on the date time formats allowed: [Custom DateTime Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.80).aspx)